# Get Id and Value of several elements in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I need to save in variables the id and value of the text box in a table, I know i can access them by:

```
var value = document.getElementById("idOne").value;
var id = document.getElementById("idOne").id;
```

But the thing is i know the id in this case, which I'mm not supposed to know and I need some way to get the id of different text boxes and save them in an array.

I'm using this table as example:

[image: Table with textBox]

What I intend to do is to save the values in two variables something like

```
id = ["idOne", "idTwo", "idTree".....
```

(where the id's are the id's from the textBoxes)

```
value = ["value1" , "value2" , "value3".....
```

And yes, the value is inside a text box :(

```html
<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idOne" name="idOne" value="value1" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTwo" name="idTwo" value="value2" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tree</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTree" name="idTree" value="value3" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idFour" name="idFour" value="value4" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Could you give us the HTML structure of your page?

Comment: <table style="width:10%"><tr><th>Number</th><th>Value</th></tr><tr><td>One</td><td><input type="text" id="idOne" name="idOne" value="value1" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td></tr><tr><td>Two</td><td><input type="text" id="idTwo" name="idTwo" value="value2" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td></tr><tr><td>Tree</td><td><input type="text" id="idTree" name="idTree" value="value3" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td></tr><tr><td>Four</td><td><input type="text" id="idFour" name="idFour" value="value4" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td></tr><table>

Using that table atm as example ant theres nothing else

Comment: Sorry, as you can tell im pretty new to this hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a minimal amount of code, here's how:

1. Select all elements of type `<input>` with [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll):

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('input')
   ```
2. The above object is a `NodeList` containing the elements as objects of type `HTMLElement`. In order to apply methods from the `Array`'s class (for example [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach), [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/map), [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce), etc...) we need to unwrap it into an actual array. To do that we will use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
   ```

   This is now an array.
3. We can apply the [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach) method to loop through each `input` element,

   > The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/) method executes a provided function once for each array element.
   >
   > - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(e => {})
   ```

   for each element of the array of elements push its value and id to the arrays `value` and `id`.

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(e => { 
     value.push(e.value);
     id.push(e.id);
   });
   ```

Here is the full code:

```js
let value = [];
let id = [];

[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(e => { value.push(e.value); id.push(e.id) })
```

```html
<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idOne" name="idOne" value="value1" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTwo" name="idTwo" value="value2" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tree</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTree" name="idTree" value="value3" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idFour" name="idFour" value="value4" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

---

In my opinion, however, it should be better to have a single object with key/value as `id`/`value`. So you can easily access an input value for a given `id`. To do so you can use the `.reduce` method:

```
const obj = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = curr.value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

```js
const obj = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = curr.value;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idOne" name="idOne" value="value1" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTwo" name="idTwo" value="value2" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tree</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTree" name="idTree" value="value3" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idFour" name="idFour" value="value4" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Or as [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) pointed out you can use a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/forEach) loop:

```
let obj = {};

[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(e => obj[e.id] = e.value);
```

```js
let obj = {};

[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(e => obj[e.id] = e.value);

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idOne" name="idOne" value="value1" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTwo" name="idTwo" value="value2" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tree</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTree" name="idTree" value="value3" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idFour" name="idFour" value="value4" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: I guess I spent too much time formatting his question ;) Do note that your answer is not understandable to a noob nor to IE

Comment: You second example is an ES6 version of my answer :) But why reduce. It does not make much sense since you are using side effects instead of actually reducing anything

Comment: This would make more sense to me `let obj={}; [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(e => { obj[e.id]=e.value; })` - yes it needs a let more but make more sense that to save the declaration

Comment: Indeed, I have added your version to my answer. To ES6 or not to ES6... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get at the inputs and store them in one object.

```js
// Plain JS (ES6 is not compatible with IE without Babel or polyfills)
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("table input"), obj = {};
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
  obj[inputs[i].id]=inputs[i].value;
}
console.log(obj);

// ES6 version 

let obj1 = {};
[...document.querySelectorAll('table input')] // destructures collection into array
  .forEach(input => obj1[input.id] = input.value);
console.log(obj1);
```

```html
<table style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idOne" name="idOne" value="value1" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTwo" name="idTwo" value="value2" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tree</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idTree" name="idTree" value="value3" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="idFour" name="idFour" value="value4" size="" maxlength="2000" /></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```